# Is it always possible to find the roots of $P(z)=az^4+bz^3+cz^2+bz+a$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^*$, by first dividing both sides by $z^2$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

A classic way to solve quartics in the form $P(z)=az^4+bz^3+cz^2+bz+a$, if we know that the roots lie on the unit circle, is to divide both sides by $z^2$ and then use the fact that if $$z=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$ then $$z^n + z^{-n}=2 \cos n\theta \qquad (*)$$

When the roots lie on the unit circle, this method will most certainly yield all of the roots of $P(z)$ because we then have the equation

$$a \left ( z^2+z^{-2} \right )+b \left ( z+z^{-1} \right )+c=0$$

which by ($*$) then becomes

$$2a \cos (2\theta) + 2b \cos \theta + c=0$$

This is a quadratic that can be solved explicitly for $\cos \theta$. One can then discover $\sin \theta$ and hence obtain all of the roots, as they must all be in the form $z=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

My question is concerning the case when the roots do **not** lie on the unit circle. We must then let the roots be $z=R \left ( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right )$. However, proceeding with the above steps, we end up with the quadratic

$$2aR \cos (2\theta) + 2bR \cos \theta + c=0$$

This is different from the previous case because now we have another unknown $R$ to deal with.

> Will the above method still work despite this problem? How can we go about finding $R$?

Comment: Since $z^2 + z^{-2} = (z + z^{-1})^2 - 2$, we can write the display equation after $(\ast)$ as $a u^2 + b u + \bar{c} = 0$ where $u = z + z^{-1}$, $\bar{c} = c + 2a$, reducing the problem to solving two quadratics (consecutively).

Comment: What if all roots dont lie on circle